# Banner ad not going away

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, ads, banner

I'm calling in a RevMob banner ad into my main menu. If I have the if statement in the "handleNotification" method alone it calls no problem. But I want the banner to go away after I hit play so I put in the else statement. With the else statement in it doesn't show the ad at all.

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) {
        _bannerWindow = [[RevMobAds session] banner];
        [_bannerWindow showAd];

} else ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"hideAd"]); {
    _bannerWindow = [[RevMobAds session] banner];
    [_bannerWindow hideAd];
}
}
```

In my main menu "initWithSize" method I use the following to call the ad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAd" object:nil];
```

When my scene transitions into my game scene(when I hit play) I have this in the game scene's "initWithSize" method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hideAd" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"hideAd"]) {
        _bannerWindow = [[RevMobAds session] banner];
    [_bannerWindow hideAd];
    }else if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"])//You should use else if 
        {
        _bannerWindow = [[RevMobAds session] banner];
        [_bannerWindow showAd];
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the code you suggest but I still had the same problem with the ad not going away when entering the GameScene. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hide your ad. After calling in view controller.

Comment: After calling in view controller?

Comment: I have a idea. Use together hide ad and scene transition method  in your main scene.